# Cannot reference System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization in a console app

Tags: .net, winforms

I'm using Visual Studio 2022 in a Console App (.Net Framework) project and cant use windows.forms, I'm using a .Net Framework Console App because I was not able do it in a .Net Core app either. Specifically trying to call a class from System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.

In order to find it at all in Console App I used nuget to retrieve  HIC.System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization, however when I try to reference it I get the below message. I'm new to .net/visual studio, is there a simple fix to this someone can assist me with?

A reference to 'System Windows_Forms' could not be added.

The ActiveX type library

'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\System.Windo ws.Forms.tlb' was exported from a .NET assembly and cannot be added as a reference.

Add a reference to the .NET assembly instead.

Below is a screen shot of the error message:

[image]

I'd appreciate any help I can get if any one knows a solution.
Best regards.

Comment: By default, it is for a WinForms project as shown by the fact that it belongs to `System.Windows.Forms` namespace. Is there a particular reason why you need to use it?

Comment: HI ChrisBD thanks for the reply. Yeah I could do it in windows forms but I was trying to type something up to access quick the command line and take a boiler plate spreadsheet I get a lot and quickly export a png of chart a frequently produce from them. I guess I could do something in forms but I'm trying to learn .net and it seems like this I can do but I dont get why I cant since it let me install that nuget package. Also, I dont understand the error message: "Add a reference to the .NET assembly instead", how do I attempt to do that?

Comment: Look at the error on screen behind. **The package does not contain any assembly that is compatible with the framework**

Comment: There is explanation in the error message why this item is not working. Not design to do such thing

Comment: Hi T.S. , thanks for responding. No way eh, ok, I was hoping there was a work around. Have a good day.

Comment: *in a Console App (.Net Framework) project and can't use Windows.Forms*: why is that? -- Are you trying to, e.g., use the formulas of the Charting namespace? Show a Chart in a Console app? Other?